# angular property undefined even after binding in Oninit

Tags: angular, angular5

i have declared a property in my ts file as shown below, and initiating it within my ngOnInit() as shown, when i do a console log of that property or try to read it from the template it says undefined[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX8VE.png)

.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-main-home',
   templateUrl: './main-home.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./main-home.component.css']
   })
export class MainHomeComponent implements OnInit {

   serviceList:product[] = [];
   tcsDbComponents:TcsDbComponent[];


constructor(private dataService:DataService, private 
   route:ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {    
  console.log("this.serviceList")

    this.dataService.getServiceList().subscribe((data) => {
    this.serviceList = data; 

   });
}

}

interface product{
  id:number;
  component:String; 
}
```

template:

```
<p>
main-home works!
</p>
<div class="test" ng-if={{flag}}>{{serviceList}}</div>
<div class="service-cards" *ngFor="let service of serviceList "
[routerLink]="['/', componentDetail.component]">
{{serviceList}}

<div class="card">
  <h1>{{service?.id}}</h1>

<h1>{{service?.component}}</h1>
<h1>{{service?.id}}</h1>

</div>
</div>
```

[code screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjR7t.png)

Comment: log the serviceList inside subscribe function

Comment: When using service call it takes time to get response. You can get it within servicecall function like following:

`ngOnInit() {
  this.dataService.getServiceList().subscribe(data => {
    this.serviceList = data;
    console.log(this.serviceList);
  });
}`

Comment: would do that but even the template reads it as undefined

Comment: Declare it like,

serviceList: procuct[] = [];

Comment: use the `?` syntax, data will show after received the response. Ex: `product?.property`

Comment: answer from @minhquanbui will work too. :)

Comment: please post code without image

Comment: Paste the code here not screenshots of code.

Comment: @HeenaVora tried that but still not working, added the template screenshot

Comment: Can you show the console.log message like @HeenaVora answer?

Comment: paste your code here @murali

Comment: can you remove the extra space after serviceList in ngFor?

Comment: got it working?

Comment: yes, thanks a lot people

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the **`console.log`** inside the **`subscribe`**, also initialize the serviceList to an empty array

```
serviceList : produce[] = [];
```

if you are using the above variable in the template inside ngFor make sure to use safe navigation operator since you are waiting for the response from asynchronous request.

```
<h1> {{service?.component}}</h1>
```

ngIf should be used with a boolean , do not use annotation

```
<div class="test" *ngIf=flag>{{serviceList | json }}</div>
```

Comment: within the subscribe the log works but when the template tries to read the variable ,it says undefined

Comment: can you post the template in question

Comment: this seems to render the data properly in the template but the console log still prints undefined, is that expected?

Comment: put the console.log inside subscribe as i mentioned